# Why variable records reports bigger size that it should?

Tags: delphi, record, delphi-10.3-rio

I tried this code:

```
  TDairyItemType = (dtFood, dtRecipe, dtExercise);
  TFourDecimalDWord = DWord;

  TDiaryItem = record
   ID: DWord;  // 4 bytes
   Positive: Boolean; // 1 byte
   GID: Word;  // 2 bytes
  case ItemType: TDairyItemType of  // 1 byte
   dtFood, dtRecipe: (ServID: Word; Serving: TFourDecimalDWord); // 6 bytes
   dtExercise: (Time: Word; Kcal: TFourDecimalDWord); // 6 bytes
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Item: TDiaryItem;
begin
  Item.ServID:= 333;
  Caption:= 'Item size: '+IntToStr(SizeOf(TDiaryItem))+'  /  Item.Time: '+IntToStr(Item.Time);
end;
```

This shows me that the size of the record is 20, but it should be 14 because the last two lines of the record use the same space. I assigned a value to `ServID` field and I read it from `Time` field and it confirms that they share the same space... What am I missing ?

Comment: Alignment of fields in a non-Packed record. "By default, the values in a structured type are aligned on word or double-word boundaries for faster access."

Comment: So, I don't save nothing if I use that `case` statement without `packed`...

Comment: You could re-arrange the fields so they fit together more with alignment. For example moving `Positive` to just before the `case` gets it down to 16 bytes..

Comment: Of course, notice that you shouldn't start packing all your records without proper consideration. The padding is there by default for a reason. I'd say it is very rare that packing is a good idea. Mainly it's useful if you need the layout to conform to some fixed binary format (file format specification, for instance). It's *very* rarely a good idea to pack just to "save memory". Almost never. Computers these days have a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment will add extra bytes. With `packed` to remove them it comes out as 14 bytes here.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TDairyItemType = (dtFood, dtRecipe, dtExercise);
  TFourDecimalDWord = DWord;

  TDiaryItem = packed record
   ID: DWord;  // 4 bytes
   Positive: Boolean; // 1 byte
   GID: Word;  // 2 bytes
  case ItemType: TDairyItemType of  // 1 byte
   dtFood, dtRecipe: (ServID: Word; Serving: TFourDecimalDWord); // 6 bytes
   dtExercise: (Time: Word; Kcal: TFourDecimalDWord); // 6 bytes
  end;

begin
  button1.Caption:= 'Item size: '+IntToStr(SizeOf(TDiaryItem));
end;
```